How can i Duplicate a slide using office js?
I am trying to develop a powerpoint add-in using officejs and it seems the simplest of the things, duplicating a slide, is not available. Anyone faced this issue before and has found a workaround it ?
I have tried to add a new slide and copy all the shapes of the slide I want to copy. But it is not working. Also, when should we use .load() function and for what items ??
Thank you for your help.

Please provide details of what you mean by "not working".

For a thorough understanding of the load() function, I recommend the book Building Office Add-ins,

I could not find any functionality to duplicate a given slide. What i have done instead is add a new slide, using slides.add(), get the selected slide and extract the shapes from that slide. for now, i have been able to get the text values from the shapes and also some formatting. Then i insert the shapes into another slide. But i found this thread that says you cannot copy images. Is there an easy way to duplicate them ??
